# Did Snape know that Draco and Harry were the masters of the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

I saw this question on [Quora.](https://www.quora.com/When-Voldemort-killed-Snape-for-the-Elder-Wand-did-Snape-know-that-the-Elder-Wand-belonged-to-Harry) I know that Snape isn't the master of the Elder Wand. Draco is the master when he disarmed Dumbledore. But later it passes to Harry as he himself disarmed Draco at Malfoy Manor.  **When Voldemort asks Snape about the Elder Wand, did Snape know at that time that it belonged to Harry?**

Comment: Is there anything about how much wandlore Snape knows?

Comment: @marcellothearcane He was in the company of Dumbledore and Voldemort. Voldemort had captured and interrogated Olivander and Dumbledore seemed to have studied wandlore enough to know that Snape would not be the Elder Wand's master if they arranged for Snape kill Dumbledore. It is unclear how much either Voldemort or Dumbledore shared with Snape.

Comment: Is the Harry Potter Wiki considered canon?

Comment: @Josafoot yeah, well it didn't turn out that Voldie got that much from Olliviander 'why didn't my wand work? *crucio!* My new wand didn't work either! *avada kedavra!*' :/

Comment: @Josafoot meh, not normally...

Comment: @marcellothearcane. That is what I thought about the Wiki. (It claims that Snape was unaware and they site the Half Blood Prince ). I guess Voldemort was more concerned about the twin wand cores and general information about the Elder Wand. However, he does seem to understand that the Elder Wand has some allegiance.

Comment: @Josafoot if you can follow the Wiki's conclusions with proof from the books, go ahead. I just don't think that it's necessarily accurate everywhere... Maybe Voldemort didn't know that Malfoy had actually got the allegiance, or he didn't know you didn't have to kill...

Comment: I know Dumbledore is a master strategist but IMO he never intended Malfoy to be the owner of the Elder Wand; he wanted (or was fine with) it passing to Snape. The fact that it played out that way probably pleased Dumbledore but it seems unlikely that he planned it out. The best support I have for my opinion is that Snape tried to argue with Voldy that V was the master of the wand (which is pretty weak, hence the comment).

Answer (score 3):

He probably hadn't even considered it.

Voldemort only discovered (and Harry by extension) that Dumbledore possessed the Elder Wand days before the Battle of Hogwarts.

Snape would have had no reason to speculate about Dumbledore's wand before then, even if he did know about wandlore, as he would have had no reason to think about looting from the corpse of someone that he was very close to.

I'm not sure if Voldemort would have told Snape that the wand he retrieved was from Dumbledore earlier than the moment right before killing him, so it's possible that Snape never got the chance to mull that idea over very much when he was staring imminent death in the face.

Even if Snape knew right around the time that Voldemort did, Voldemort certainly wouldn't have admitted weakness in himself by admitting that the wand was resisting him, up until the boathouse where he had already resolved to kill the only person that he told.

So, at the very most, we can say that Snape might have suspected that he himself, or Draco, might be the master of the Elder wand in the days between Voldemort getting the wand and the Battle of Hogwarts.

However, if in this time frame Snape had considered that killing Dumbledore would make him the master of the wand, he would know that he was in danger of being killed by Voldemort, and as it was still necessary for him to provide Harry with the information of him being a Horcrux I think he might have made more of an effort to get that information to him.

If he knew that it was Draco that had become the master of the wand by disarming Dumbledore, he would likely have warned him about being in danger. He wouldn't want to see his favorite student, and someone he has looked out for for a long time, potentially being on the wrong side of the Dark Lord, considering that Voldemort doesn't seem to be the type to disarm someone in order to get the power that they have.

There is no way that he could have known that Harry was the wand's owner, as he wasn't at Malfoy Manor when Harry disarmed Draco, and I don't think that anyone who was there would have provided him with such trivial information.

So all the evidence points to the fact that he didn't know who the true owner of the Elder wand was, or that he ever gave it a moment's thought before the conversation in the boathouse, at which point it was already too late for him to seriously think it through.

Comment: Additionally, he wouldn't have known what the Elder Wand even was since he wasn't mates with Grindelwald, he probably wasn't familiar with The Tale of the Three Brothers and the two people who knew the most (Voldemort and Dumbledore) were both highly secretive people. Like the rest of the Death Eaters, the most that Snape probably knew was a passing recognition that Voldemort's wand had changed - and this wouldn't have gone much beyond, "Hey, the boss has got a new wand".

Comment: The fact that he hadn't had a chance to think it through explains why he had no argument to resist, no facts to present that might save his life.

Answer (score 1):

I think at best, Snape would know he himself is not the master of the Elder Wand. If he understood wandlore, he would know that simply killing Dumbledore would not transfer the wand's loyalty to him. Also, since Snape arrived at the platform of the tower and found Dumbledore wandless, Snape would have no idea who disarmed Dumbledore (if anyone did).

If Snape did not know wandlore, then he would have no clue as to the master of the Elder Wand. I can easily imagine Alan Rickman saying "no idea..." :-)

Comment: "*If he understood wandlore, he would know that simply killing Dumbledore would not transfer the wand's loyalty to him*" I think it does for the Elder wand. It's very fickle. The point is, Draco disarmed Dumbledore *before* Snape killed him.

Comment: @marcellothearcane You're absolutely right, but my point is that Snape did not know Dumbledore had been disarmed by Malfoy, as he arrived after the disarming. The most Snape could know -- if he had studied wandlore -- was that the Elder Wand would never be loyal to himself just for killing the wand's owner.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Snape knows Harry is the new owner. Because as we all know, Snape is a Legilimens (meaning he can read minds as long as he wants to). 
Since Harry nor Draco know who the real owner is, even though he read their minds, he'll get nothing.

Comment: No, Snape probably didn't know Harry had stolen Draco's wand. He may have known it didn't belong to himself, though.

Comment: Yes, maybe he did know that the wand does not belong to him (or not). But the question here is if he know that Harry is the real owner, which I think is not because Harry himself didn't know it either.